# Why does this cause a segfault?

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I'm just trying to malloc an array of strings and copy input from a file into this array. This combination of lines causes a segfault and I don't know why.

```
int count = 0;
char **output = (char**)malloc(numLines*257);
fgets(output[count], 257, input);
```

Comment: Don't cast malloc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've allocated space for an array of pointers, but you haven't initialized any of those pointers.

```
int count = 0;
char **output = malloc(numLines*sizeof(char *));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
  output[i] = malloc(257);
}
fgets(output[count], 257, input);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually wanted to do here was allocate a memory for `numLines` pointers (strings) and then allocate memory for every string so that each of these is capable of holding `257` `char`s:

```
int i, count = 0;
char **output = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numLines);
for (i = 0; i < numLines; ++i)
    output[i] = malloc(257);
...
fgets(output[count], 257, input);
```

just don't forget to clean it up once you don't need it anymore:

```
for (i = 0; i < numLines; ++i)
    free(output[i]);
free(output);
output = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0;
char **output = (char**)malloc(numLines*257);
fgets(output[count], 257, input); // here You are going wrong, with out allocating memory you are trying to read.
```

if you want to read string

```
char *output = malloc(MAX_LENGTH+1); //allocate memory
    fgets(output[count], MAX_LENGTH+1, input);
```

if you want to read array of strings

```
char **output = malloc(MAX_NUM_STRINGS * sizeof(char *)); //allocate Number of pointers 
for(count=0;count<MAX_NUM_STRINGS;count++)
{   output[count]=malloc(SIZE_OF_EACH_STRING+1);  //allocate memory for each pointer,  
    //You are accessing with out allocating memory  
    fgets(output[count], SIZE_OF_EACH_STRING+1, input); 
}
```